# move local repo to remote single file

Tags: linux, git

I apologize if this has been asked somewhere else and I missed it. I've found many questions and answers that are close to what I'm trying to do, but none that fit exactly.

I have local files and projects in a local git repository. I created the repository a few months back as a way to safeguard and track my own work. The rest of our company uses SVN so I am the first to use git here. I set it up in my home directory on a Linux server. This repo contains many commits, branches, and tags that span my work over the past few months.

I want to move that repo to a more accessible location within our company's Linux server (not in my home directory) so others can clone and work with the entire repo (including all the tags, branches, history, etc.) as they see fit.

I've thought about copying or moving the entire file structure, but I want it to be a single file - i.e. myRepo.git.

How do I do this so that myRepo.git contains all the information I've committed such that when someone clones this repo and runs 'gitk --all', they will see all the branches, tags, etc.?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: _"I want it to be a single file - i.e. myRepo.git"_ -- why?

Comment: I'm not married to it being a single file. I was confused. myRepo.git seemed like a single file because of the extension. I "cd"ed into it and found out it was a directory. I'm still learning about both git and Linux - still a ways to go I guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can `git clone --bare` your repo from somewhere other people can access it.

The most basic remote Git repo is nothing but a bare clone. A bare clone means it doesn't have a checkout, it's just the contents of the `.git` directory. Having a checkout would mean people might try to use that checkout as their own git working directory and make changes and that would get confusing with other people pushing changes to the repository.

For example, I'll make a new repository in `foo/` and commit a file.

```
$ git init foo
Reinitialized existing Git repository in /Users/schwern/tmp/foo/.git/
$ rm -rf foo
$ git init foo
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/schwern/tmp/foo/.git/
$ cd foo
$ touch this
$ git add this
$ git ci -m 'First commit'
[master (root-commit) 1a0bddf] First commit
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 this
```

Then I'll make a bare clone of it into `bar/` (cloning doesn't have to happen over a network).

```
$ git clone --bare foo bar
$ ls
HEAD  config  description  hooks  info  objects  packed-refs  refs
```

Instead of the checkout, it has the contents of the `.git` directory.

Now I can clone from that.

```
$ git clone bar baz
Cloning into 'baz'...
done.
$ cd baz/
$ git log
commit 1a0bddf415f48d71fa3aacc79c07c233d91ed4a9 (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: Michael G. Schwern <schwern@pobox.com>
Date:   Tue Feb 14 12:01:13 2017 -0800

    First commit
```

---

That's cloning on a local filesystem. Git will, of course, clone over a network. Typically it uses `ssh` or `https`.  `git clone user@host/path` is really `ssh`ing into `host` as `user` and copying what's in `path`.

So you can put your repo anywhere the other folks have `ssh` access, like a dev server, or the same host that has the SVN server.

---

That's the most bare bones way to share your Git repository. There are plenty of more sophisticated Git servers out there that provide web access and more protocols. Everything from the very sparse [GitWeb](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-GitWeb) to [Gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/), a Github clone you can host locally for free.

You can read more about this in [Pro Git's chapter on Git Servers](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-The-Protocols).

Answer (score 0):

A fully functional git repo is *not* a single file, and there is no way to make it so.  That said, copying your working repo isn't the best thing to do either.

If having a single file is more important that having the repo be fully functional - i.e. you don't care if your coworkers can push to it - then you can create a bundle file.

```
git bundle create /path/to/my/repo.bundle --all
```

Your coworkers can clone from this, add it as a remote, pull or fetch from it... but they can't push to it (and neither can you; to add to it you'd have to recreate it).

A shared repo to be cloned from should normally be a bare repo.  This is roughly equivalent to a copy of the .git directory from your working repo.  If your existing repo is at /path/to/my/repo, you can create a suitable bare repo at /path/to/shared/repo by saying

```
cd /path/to/shared
git clone --mirror /path/to/my/repo
```

Note that I used `--mirror` instead of `--bare`; this has to do with how refs are copied and will work better if you intend this to be treated as the origin henceforth.

And yet at this point /path/to/my/repo is still considered the upstream.  To fix that

```
cd /path/to/shared/repo
git remote remove origin
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin /path/to/shared/repo
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. I'm not able to do "git remote remove origin". I get the following "error: Unknown subcommand: remove". I've also tried "rm" and "-d". I'll look around for the correct way to do this - I get the idea.

Comment: Hmm... could be an old version of git, but then I would've expected `git remote rm origin` to work.  Not sure about why that would be.